# Comportamiento extraño HTML si borro comentario inicial

Tags: html, idioma

Tengo un documento HTML de un ejercicio que estoy haciendo con este contenido

```
<!--
11 aciertos = 10€
* -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "es">
<head>
    <title>Practica 6.2 - Quinieleitor</title>
    <script src = "quinieleitor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Y por último, un archivo js que aporta el contenido final de la página.
Al abrir el documento HTML en el navegador, aparece algo así...

> ¿Deseas introducir la quiniela manualmente?

Pero si borro la línea 2, o las líneas 1, 2 y 3 (el comentario), entonces lo que aparece al cargar el documento HTML es esto...

> Â¿Deseas introducir la quiniela manualmente?

Y lo mismo ocurre en el resto del documento para cada palabra que contenga una tilde un carácter "extraño" como por ejemplo "€".

No le encuentro ningún sentido...¿alguien sabe por qué puede ocurrir esto?

Saludos.

Comment: Te hace falta este meta: `<meta charset="utf-8">` justo después de la etiqueta `<head>` de apertura

Comment: si quitas o comentas la linea del script sigue ocurriendo?

Comment: Eso es exactamente lo que pasaba. ¿Puedes convertir el comentario en respuesta para que te lo vote como respuesta correcta? Y en cualquier caso...¿Cómo es posible que el que hubiera o no un comentario inicial hiciera que se mostrara bien o mal? En fin...GRACIAS!

Comment: Respecto a lo del script, si lo comento, la página ya no tiene ningún tipo de contenido o texto, asi que no puedo probarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es la codificación de tu documento HTML, debe agregar la siguiente etiqueta `<meta charset="UTF-8">` dentro de tu `<head>` `</head>`

```
<!--
11 aciertos = 10€
* -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Practica 6.2 - Quinieleitor</title>
    <script src = "quinieleitor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```